# Installing PHP: bash: ./configure: Permission denied

Tags: php, centos7

I'm trying to install PHP for PThreads. ([PHP - Installation Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php#116368))

in installation I need config but when I using this command:

```
# ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-config-file-path=/etc --enable-maintainer-zts
bash: ./configure: Permission denied
```

I tried to give configure the permissions:

```
# chmod +x configure
#
```

and again output is:

```
# ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-config-file-path=/etc --enable-maintainer-zts
bash: ./configure: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ls -lah in the directory to show the current owner of the files. Most likely your account isn’t the owner and you need to do a sudo chown -r user:group ./* inside the base directory of the php src

Comment: `-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root 2.6M Dec 17 16:00 configure` and other files and folders have `-rwxrwxrwx` with user `root` but still I run my command with `sudo ./confi ... `  i will receive: `sudo: unable to execute ./configure: Permission denied `

Comment: [CentOS Becoming Rooth](https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/BecomingRoot) See sudo section.

The files were downloaded using the root user and thats where your issues are.

Comment: Assuming you are not a root user...

`cd  ~/` <- change to your home dir
`wget https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.1.tar.gz` <- Download PHP 7.4.1 src
`tar zxf php-7.4.1` <- unpack the tar file
`cd ../php-7.4.1`
`./configure`
`make`
`sudo make install`

Answer (score 1):

For me, It was resolved after installing it from `home directory`.

In my case, I was trying to install from `/tmp` and it was throwing the permission denied even with root and changing the owner to root with 777 permission. Also, installation path was remote mount.

Extracted the source code in home directory and it worked!!